# How to handle void pointers in SWIG director methods in Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to wrap a C++ library as a Python library.
The C++ library exposes abstract classes for the user to inherit from it, so we use directors in SWIG to handle. It works mostly OK (with some tweaking).

One issue is that this C++ class has two methods as follows:

```
class Base {
  void* getObject();
  void  doSomething(void* o);
}
```

The user is expected to implement these methods and the object returned by the user in getObject() is then passed to the doSomething() method.

The problem is that when going through SWIG, the doSomething() method in Python receives a SwigPyObject with wrapped type 'void*', so we cannot use the original Python object methods as we would hope.
And casting is not an option since it's Python (or is it?).

Does anyone have any insights?

I found some related issues here and there, but none of them seem to address exactly my case, and I've already tried many things to solve it, without any success.

Let me know if you need more details and I'll provide it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand the design you've got here - why void* and not a type heirarchy. In real usage what types do you actually use?

Comment: What we provide is a library and it's up to the user to define what is the type of the object returned by getObject().

We thought about create some sort of empty Object class and have getObject return a pointer to an instance of this Object class. The user would then have to create classes that inherit from this Object class.

But then, we still have the issue that in the doSomething() Python method, the object passed in argument will only expose methods from the Object class, and not the user-defined derived class methods.

Comment: So the Python code could pass anything in and then expect to get it back later on, but only python implementations need understand what it actually is?

Comment: Yes precisely! The C++ library does not have to know anything about the object passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

First off we want to make your code into something real and runnable. I wrote my own test.hh based on the little code you've shown that lets us exercise this design somewhat:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
  void runMe() {
    std::cerr << "Getting object\n";
    void *result = getObject();
    std::cerr << "Got: " << result << "\n";
    doSomething(result);
    std::cerr << "Did a thing\n";
  }

  virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
  virtual void* getObject() = 0;
  virtual void  doSomething(void* o) = 0;
};
```

We can initially wrap that as something like this:

```cpp
%module(directors="1") test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%feature("director") Base;

%include "test.hh"
```

And produce a test case to show how we'd like it to work in Python:

```py
import test

class Foobar(test.Base):
    def getObject(self):
        return [1,2,3]

    def doSomething(self, thing):
        print(thing)

f=Foobar()
f.runMe()
```

But this won't yet work at this stage because we've not told SWIG how to meaningfully handle `void*` inside Python.

The general idea here is that we want to make the `void*` get used as a `PyObject*` inside the interface. We can do that wit a directorin and directorout typemap pairing. Broadly there are two issues we need to solve:

1. How can we make the reference counting work properly and not leak?
2. What happens if the `void*` we've got isn't really a `PyObject*`?

If we start out by assuming that there's a 1:1 mapping between `getObject()` calls and `doSomething()` calls then the reference counting is fairly simple and we can just write two typemaps in our interface that retain a reference to a `PyObject` and then cast it back from `void*` when needed (Note that we've also sidestepped issue #2 completely here by adding the 1:1 restriction).

So with those two typemaps our interface becomes:

```cpp
%module(directors="1") test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%feature("director") Base;

%typemap(directorout) void *getObject %{
  Py_INCREF($1);
  $result = $1;
%}

%typemap(directorin) void *o %{
  $input = static_cast<PyObject*>($1);
  // Director call will decref when we're done here - it assumes ownership semantics, not borrowed
%}

%include "test.hh"
```

And when we test it like this:

```
swig -Wall -python -py3 -c++ test.i
g++ -Wall -Wextra  -shared -o _test.so -I/usr/include/python3.5 test_wrap.cxx -std=c++11 -fPIC
python3 run.py 
Getting object
Got: 0x7fce97b91c48
[1, 2, 3]
Did a thing
```

However if we change the sematics here to not be exactly 1:1 then we've got a problem, for example make `runMe` be this:

```cpp
void runMe() {
  std::cerr << "Getting object\n";
  void *result = getObject();
  std::cerr << "Got: " << result << "\n";
  doSomething(result);
  std::cerr << "Second time\n";
  doSomething(result);
  std::cerr << "Did a thing\n";
}
```

Which segfaults now because the reference gets decremented after the first call to `doSomething` has completed.

At this stage the obvious thing to do is to add a call to `Py_INCREF` in the directorin typemap, however that's not quite the whole story - we'll *never* call release the result of `getObject()` now and it simply goes out of scope at the end of `runMe()`.

The way I'd be inclined to solve that is by adding another call into your `Base` interface:

```
virtual void cleanupThing(void* o) {} // Default nothing, not mandatory
```

With that in place we can make your SWIG interface implement (and hide if we want) that call completely inside the Python director. The way to do that is with some `%rename` and `%ignore` and some macro trickery:

So with the following adaptation to the SWIG interface we can now work correctly on the second incarnation of `runMe`:

```cpp
%module(directors="1") test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%feature("director") PyBase;

%typemap(directorout) void *getObject %{
  Py_INCREF($1);
  $result = $1;
%}

%typemap(directorin) void *o %{
  $input = static_cast<PyObject*>($1);
  Py_INCREF($input); // Not borrowed now
  // Director call will decref when we're done here
%}

// Python won't even know cleanupThing existed because we use it internally in the Python binding    
%ignore PyBase::cleanupThing;
%feature("nodirector") PyBase::cleanupThing;
// This is a sleight of hand trick with SWIG so we can add another type into the hierarchy without anyone really noticing
%rename(Base) PyBase;

%{
  class PyBase : public Base {
    void cleanupThing(void *o) {
      Py_DECREF(o);
    }
  };
%}

#define Base PyBase

%include "test.hh"
```

Throw in a call to `cleanupThing` from `runMe`:

```
void runMe() {
  std::cerr << "Getting object\n";
  void *result = getObject();
  std::cerr << "Got: " << result << "\n";
  doSomething(result);
  std::cerr << "Second time\n";
  doSomething(result);
  std::cerr << "Did a thing\n";
  cleanupThing(result);
}
```

When run now does give:

```
Getting object
Got: 0x7ff65dccfd08
[1, 2, 3]
Second time
[1, 2, 3]
Did a thing
```

(Other possible solutions exist particularly if the semantics are more complicated than simply a local variable that gets passed back and forth to the same instance).

Comment: Hi again, I tried it tonight. First, I had to implement the PyBase constructors for it to work. But then I had an issue because the dynamic library does not have certain symbols. In particular, my 'Base' class is used in a template class like 'List<Base>', but when I compile the Python SWIG wrapper, I have missing symbols 'List<PyBase>' at link time and I am not sure how to fix that. It looks like the "#define Base PyBase" line is not working fully. Any hints?

Comment: I see the problem here. Simplest answer is to make `cleanupThing` a fully fledged virtual member function inside `Base` and skip the whole workaround with #define`

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a bit more. I actually already have a viurtal cleanedupThing method in my Base class. But should I just remove the #define line or all the lines of the second part of your code example? I still need to implement the cleanup somewhere.